# Python sublist not working for long

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I am trying to sublist an list which contains long.

```
a = [ -846930886, -1714636915, 424238335, -1649760492]
print(a[2:1])
```

This returns `[]`. What's happening? I could find only this way of sub listing.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the slice `a[2:1]` to return?

Comment: [424238335]. Okay. I got it. It's not the size. It's the start and end index. My bad.

Comment: What numbers exist starting at two, ending at one, and incrementing by 1?

Answer (score 3):

`a[2:1]` is not a valid `slicing` and will return `empty` list.

The correct syntax is `object[start:end:inteval]`. If you want to traverse in backward you should add `interval`

```
>>> print(a[2:1:-1])
[424238335]
```

Another approach will be with passing single `index`

```
>>> print(a[-2])
424238335
```

Or if you want to traverse in forward direction use :

```
>>> print(a[1:2])
[-1714636915]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sublist starts after it ends.So,

```
print(a[1:2])
```

will give you

```
[-1714636915].
```